# AWS Lightsail with custom domain. A URL without trailing slash would redirect to an EC2 URL

Tags: amazon-web-services, bitnami

I am working on static content in Lightsail (LAMP/PHP8).
I have also assigned my own domain name and set up StaticIP and Distribution.

`https://example.com/hoge/`
`https://www.example.com/hoge/`
=> 'index.html' is displayed without any problem.

`https://example.com/hoge`
`https://www.example.com/hoge`
=> Redirected to http://ec2-xxx.compute.amazonaws.com/hoge/ and 'index.html' is displayed.

It is not clear why it is redirected, nor where the URL ec2-xxx came from.
Please help me.